# Cygwin program compiled but not runnable

Tags: bash, compiler-errors, compilation, cygwin

I just installed [CD-HIT](http://weizhong-lab.ucsd.edu/cd-hit/wiki/doku.php?id=cd-hit_user_guide) and followed these instructions:

```
Installation
Most CD-HIT programs were written in C++. Installing CD-HIT package is very simple: 
download current CD-HIT at http://bioinformatics.org/cd-hit, for example cd-hit-2006-0215.tar.gz
unpack the file with ” tar xvf cd-hit-2006-0215.tar.gz --gunzip”
change dir by “cd cd-hit-2006”
compile the programs by “make”
you will have all cd-hit programs compiled
```

I followed these steps and indeed `.exe` files were made:

```
cdhit.c++          cdhit-est-2d.c++               clstr_select_rep.pl
cd-hit.exe         cd-hit-est-2d.exe              clstr_size_histogram.pl
cdhit.o            cdhit-est-2d.o                 clstr_size_stat.pl
cdhit-2d.c++       cd-hit-para.pl                 clstr_sort_by.pl
cd-hit-2d.exe      cdhit-utility.c++              clstr_sort_prot_by.pl
cdhit-2d.o         cdhit-utility.h                clstr_sql_tbl.pl
cd-hit-2d-para.pl  cdhit-utility.o                clstr_sql_tbl_sort.pl
cdhit-454.c++      ChangeLog                      clstr2tree.pl
cd-hit-454.exe     clstr_cut.pl                   clstr2txt.pl
cdhit-454.o        clstr_list.pl                  clstr2xml.pl
cd-hit-auxtools    clstr_list_sort.pl             doc
cdhit-common.c++   clstr_merge.pl                 FET.pl
cdhit-common.h     clstr_merge_noorder.pl         license.txt
cdhit-common.o     clstr_quality_eval.pl          make_multi_seq.pl
cdhit-div.c++      clstr_quality_eval_by_link.pl  Makefile
cd-hit-div.exe     clstr_reduce.pl                plot_2d.pl
cdhit-div.o        clstr_renumber.pl              plot_len1.pl
cd-hit-div.pl      clstr_rep.pl                   psi-cd-hit
cdhit-est.c++      clstr_reps_faa_rev.pl          README
cd-hit-est.exe     clstr_rev.pl                   usecases
cdhit-est.o        clstr_select.pl
```

However when I typ: `cd-hit-est` in the cygwin command line, it will say: `-bash: cd-hit.exe: command not found`. I'm not able to figure out why this is happening. Even when I'm in the folder were the `.exe` files are located it still will give the same error.

Comment: Let me guess, you're in the directory where the executable file is located? Then try e.g. `./cd-hit-est` (i.e. prefix the program with the current path).

Comment: Well that's a good guess hahah @Someprogrammerdude but then I can only run it while linking the path of this map instead of just having to type cd-hit-est?

Comment: You could always append the directory to the path (while in the directory, do e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)`). Important note: Do not add the current directory `.` to the `PATH`. It will always the *current* directory no matter where you are, and it's usually considered to be a security risk. If you want to make the `PATH` change permanent, then add the command (with the correct path of course) in your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) file.

Comment: Thankyou so much, learned something today! @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Does the Makefile have an `install` target?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run command without a path, bash tries to find the command name in each directory from the PATH environment variable.
Usually current directory "." is not in the PATH so you have to run command adding absolute or relative path before command name:

```
./cd-hit.exe
```

or

```
/absolute/path/to/your/cd-hit/program/cd-hit.exe
```

If you want to permanently run command **cd-hit.exe** from anywhere, just add the directory where cd-hit was compiled to any existing auto-loaded bash profile files:

```
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_profile
```

like

```
PATH=$PATH:/absolute/path/to/your/cd-hit/program
export PATH
```